# Bind comma separated list to checkboxes in Angular 9

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In my reactive form I have an array that I bind the checkbox list to using following syntax:
structure of array is {id:number, name:string}

**TS**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.initFCForm();
 this.addCheckboxes();
}

initFCForm(): void {
this.fcForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  frequency : new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  rules: new FormArray([])
});
}

get rulesFormArray() {
  return this.fcForm.controls.rules as FormArray;
}
private addCheckboxes() {
  this.businessrules.forEach(() => this.rulesFormArray.push(new FormControl(false)));
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <label class="col-md-7" formArrayName="rules" 
         *ngFor="let rule of rulesFormArray.controls; let i = index">
               <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
                                    {{businessrules[i].name}}
  </label>
```

Now I need to populate it when the page loads to have the **first** and the **third** option selected. I have tried the following code but it only select first two options.

**TS**

```
this.fc.rules.patchValue([1,3])
```

Comment: You should be setting the checkbox's `formControl` to the `rule` property and not the `formControlName` with the current index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this.fc.rules.patchValue([1,3]), it will set value 1 to first control of the rules FormArray and 3 to the second control of the rules FormArray but nothing to third.

Checkbox formcontrol expects a boolean value (true or false) and here, when setting 1 and 3 using patch, values are automatically 'converted' to true because these are truthy values.

If you want to have the first and third value populated, try this :

this.fc.rules.patchValue([true,null, true])

Comment: Thank you @thib_o_o  that did it!